# Какой интервал между сообщениями вк?

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, спам

Я написал простенький скрипт на python, который от лица группы спамит под пост. Вначале я убирал задержку, и впринципе он спамил по 70 комментов, потом возникала капча, но она сама пропадала и бот продолжал. Но, вот, буквально после 69к комментариев, после возникновения капчи - сразу появлялась новая... Какой лучше интервал поставить между комментариями, чтобы можно было оставить так скрипт и не парится по поводу капчи?
Кстати, и ещё вопрос, если капча возникает, то она возникает именно для комментирования этого поста, или же для той группы, которая спамит(это важно, тк у меня спамит 4 группы, и надо узнать, ставить ши задержку между каждым смс, или же задержка после того, как каждая группа напишет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно выяснить только экспериментируя с разными интервалами. Сам "вк" эти тайминги целенаправленно скрывает от разработчиков, пользующихся API.

Comment: А есть объяснение тому, что раньше капча сама пропадала, да и к тому же, бот успевал наспамить 70 смс, а сейчас капча сама не пропадает + всего 5 смс?